# Compile another Maven project using Maven Compiler API (CompilerMojo)

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin, java-compiler-api, mutation-testing

I'm working on a Maven project that injects and runs some tests in another Maven projects. I already managed to inject them, however, I'm struggling to programmatically compile the other Maven project given its path.
I tried Java Compiler API and Maven Compiler API but couldn't manage to do so.

Does any one know any way to programmatically compile a Maven project given its path from another Maven project?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of direct API calls. Yet I think your goal is achievable, and it would come with the advantage of separating JVMs...

Make 'another Maven project' excecute a command that essentially calls maven to compile 'a Maven project'. If need be, use the [AntRun Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html) and [Ant's exec task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) for this.